# Sort a 2d array with rows containing year, then month, then day values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, multidimensional-array

I generate an array with rearranged date values in it

```
$totert = [
    ['2011', '07', '25'],
    ['2011', '07', '27'],
    ['2011', '06', '25'],
    ['2011', '06', '02'],
    ['2011', '05', '25'],
    ['2011', '05', '15']
];
```

Expected result:

```
[
    ['2011', '05', '15'],
    ['2011', '05', '25'],
    ['2011', '06', '02'],
    ['2011', '06', '25'],
    ['2011', '07', '27'],
    ['2011', '07', '25']
]
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of questions like this one already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort+date

Answer (score 2):

Use [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and provide a custom comparison function.

```
$totert = array(
    array('2011','07','25'), 
    array('2011','07','27'), 
    array('2011','06','25'), 
    array('2011','06','02'), 
    array('2011','05','25'), 
    array('2011','05','15')
);
usort($totert, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)implode('', $a) - (int)implode('', $b);
});

print_r(array_map(function($v) {
    return implode('-', $v);
}, $totert));
```

Comment: Use this solution if you need the `$totert` intact after sorting, but use KingCrunch's solution, if this doesn't matter. Using the built-in `sort()` function is faster than using the `usort()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamps = array_map (function ($date) {
  return mktime(0,0,0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
}, $totert;

sort($timestamps);
```

The values are now UNIX-timestamps, buts ith `date()` its very easy to create any format you like again.

Another solution is to use simple string comparison

```
$dates = array_map (function ($date) {
  return implode('-', $date);
}, $totert;

sort($dates, SORT_STRING);
```

You can split (`explode()`) the single values at `-` again, if you really need the dates as an array.

Comment: Works in PHP 5.3. In PHP 5.2 and before, the function has to be defined normally and a string has to be passed to `array_map` (just saying this for completeness).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $totert = array(  
 array('2011','07','25'), 
 array('2011','07','27'), 
 array('2011','06','25'), 
 array('2011','06','02'), 
 array('2011','05','25'), 
 array('2011','05','15'));

function convert_to_date(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = $item[0].'-'.$item[1].'-'.$item[2];
}

array_walk($totert, 'convert_to_date');
sort($totert);
print_r($totert);
```

Comment: You are converting strings to integers (implicitely), then computing an integer timestamp, and finally computing back the **original strings** using the `date` function.  This is a rather big overhead, since you could achieve exactly the same by just concatenating the strings: `return "$item[0]-$item[1]-$item[2]"`.  By the way, you are missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion, the replacement of line in function with  `$item = $item[0].'-'.$item[1].'-'.$item[2]; ` will output the same. But here you dont need `return ` statement, as I'm taking the array item reference, it will directly modify the array item.

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` is perfectly suited to order your rows of date values because each row has an equal length and your columns are arranged in a "big-endian" fashion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PsFho))

```
sort($totert);
```